# How to add if statment in select query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to write select query from below condition

```
$query = \App\Models\User::where('id', $user->id)
```

if this user is_email_verify == 1 means select

```
$query = \App\Models\User::where('id', $user->id)->slect('is_email_verify')->first();
```

if this user is_phone_verify == 1 means select

```
$query = \App\Models\User::where('id', $user->id)->slect('is_email_verify', 'is_email_verify')->first();
```

Select  column name base on that value

if this user have is_email_verify then select is_email_verify.
if this user have is_phone_verify then select is_phone_verify.
if this user have both verify then select is_phone_verify and is_email_verify.

Comment: Where does the `$user` comes from ? Did you try anything ?

Comment: @xenooooo Its login user.

Comment: does the table of the login user and the `User::class` model separate ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass a ternary condition into addSelect method.

```
return \App\Models\User::where('id', $user->id)
    ->addSelect($user->is_email_verify === 1
         ? 'is_email_verify'
         : 'is_phone_verify'
    )->first();
```

Regards.